# Angular Filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this Schema in mongoDB:

```
var CostSchema = new Schema({
    item: String,
    value: Number
});

var AttachmentsSchema = new Schema({
    item: String,
    url: String
})

var ServiceSchema = new Schema({
    item: String, // maybe another Schema [] to be able to search for this criteria
    description:String,
    worker: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Worker'}, //Saves Worker ID 
    date_assigned: Date,
    price:Number
});

var JobsSchema = new Schema({ 
    manager: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Admin', required:true}, // Saves Manager Name       
    propertie: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Propertie', required:true}, //Saves Property Name 
    unit: String,
    completed: Boolean,
    costs: [CostSchema],
    services:[ServiceSchema], 
    totalPrice: Number,
    totalCost:Number,
    poNumber: { type : String, unique: true, sparse:true },
    invoiceNumber: { type : String, unique: true, sparse:true },
    notes: String,
    date_completed: Date,
    attachments: [AttachmentsSchema],
    notification_sent: Boolean
});
```

So depending on the Job it will have a completed date or not i am trying to apply the following filter in the front-end

```
<div class="page-header col-xs-12">
  <h3 class ='text-center'>Pending Jobs</h3> 
  <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-center">
    <label for="searchJobBox1">Filter</label>
    <input ng-model = 'job.$' type="text" class="form-control" id="searchJobBox1" placeholder="Quick Filter...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3 text-center">
    <label for="jobPropertyFilter" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Property</label>
    <div>
      <select ng-model = 'job.propertie._id' class="form-control" id='jobPropertyFilter'>
        <option></option>
        <option  value = '{{property._id}}' ng-repeat ='property in properties'>
        {{property.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 text-center">
    <label for="jobWorkerFilter" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Worker</label>
    <div>
      <select ng-model = 'job.services.worker._id' class="form-control" id='jobWorkerFilter'>
        <option></option>
        <option  value = '{{worker._id}}' ng-repeat ='worker in workers'>
        {{worker.first}} {{worker.last}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2 text-center">
    <label for="jobManagerFilter" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Manager</label>
    <div>
      <select ng-model = 'job.manager._id' class="form-control" id='jobManagerFilter'>
        <option></option>
        <option  value = '{{admin._id}}' ng-repeat ='admin in admins'>
        {{admin.first}} {{admin.last}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two ng-repeats in place as follows:
1) Is Working Perfectly

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat = 'job in jobs| filter:job:strict' ng-if='!job.date_completed' >
```

2)

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat = 'job in jobs| filter:job:strict' ng-if='job.date_completed' >
```

For some reason that i haven't been able to figure out, Angular will apply the filter to every job with a date_completed property and they are not being displayed it does not have anything to do with the ng-if, which is working just fine.

Any advice?

Comment: It's a little unclear exactly what you'd like to do here. Are you trying to get these to filter independently? Or is one not filtering while the other is?

Answer (score 1):

On your second example `ng-if` would display the element only if `job.date_completed` is defined.

I can only asume that `job.date_completed` is `*undefined*`.

Try to use `console.log` for printing the value of `job.date_completed`